# Rails 4 params.require().permit() not considering one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble using the `params.require().permit()` method because it is not considering one of the attributes I'm setting to it, namely the attribute `:on`

What I have is this:

```
def event_recurrence_params
  params.require(:event_recurrence).permit(:room_id, [...], :on, :every)
end
```

Then, when I call `event_recurrence_params`, the answer is

```
>> event_recurrence_params
=> {"room_id"=>"1", [...], "every"=>"week"}
```

even though the value of `params[:event_recurrence]` is

```
>> params[:event_recurrence]
=> {"room_id"=>"1", [...], "on"=>["wednesday"], "every"=>"week"}
```

As you can see, the `:on` attribute is not being considered in the `event_recurrence_params` even though the attribute is permitted and the `params[:event_recurrence]` include it.

Any ideas?  I've tried lots of things but none of it worked.
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters):

> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric,
>   TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO,
>   ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.
>
> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted
>   scalar values map the key to an empty array:

So you need to do this:

```
params.require(:event_recurrence).permit(:room_id, [...], :every, on: [])
```

Comment: Thank you! One small change though: `params.require(:event_recurrence).permit(:room_id, [...], on: [], :every)` threw me a syntax error, but changing it to `params.require(:event_recurrence).permit(:room_id, [...], :every, on: [])` made it work (notice the array is at the end).