# Array in JSON not properly passed to Database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, json, parameters

I am trying to create a new entry in my database which contains an array `images`.

Using `Product.new("title":"Hello World", "images":["a.jpg","b.jpg"])` I can create a new entry without problems. But when I try passing the parameters to my API, the array remains empty (all the other fields are filled).

The request I used:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"title":"Hello World",  "images":["a.jpg", "b.jpg"], "api_key":"API_KEY"}' http://localhost:3000/api/products
```

Parameters are passed using:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:id, :title, :images)
end
```

A new database entry is then created using:

```
Product.new(product_params)
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `images: []`.

via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18641790/1076207

> From the documentation [https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters]
>
> The permitted scalar types are String, Symbol, NilClass, Numeric,
>   TrueClass, FalseClass, Date, Time, DateTime, StringIO, IO,
>   ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile and Rack::Test::UploadedFile.
>
> To declare that the value in params must be an array of permitted
>   scalar values map the key to an empty array:

```
def product_params
  params.require(:product).permit(:title, images: [])
end
```